# Docker API - Exec start returns garbage bytes

Tags: docker, docker-api

I am posting with Postman through Docker API 1.41 an Exec command to a container to get md5, sha1 and sha256 of some files on same line. Works OK but it returns garbage at the beginning of the response.

Can anyone spot the problem?

```
POST http://localhost:2375/v1.41/containers/{containerid}/exec

{
  "AttachStdin": false,
  "AttachStdout": true,
  "AttachStderr": true,
  "DetachKeys": "ctrl-p,ctrl-q",
  "Tty": false,
  "Cmd": [
    "sh", 
    "-c",
    "find /sbin/* -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'paste -d \" \" <(md5sum \"$@\") <(sha1sum \"$@\") <(sha256sum \"$@\") <(du -lh \"$@\")' bash | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1,3,5,6"
  ]
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "Id": "5243df9ea1d665d5eef78593c8d1031e4a3c61feb20267a974119a7f70d87d24"
}
```

Starting command:

```
POST http://localhost:2375/v1.41/exec/5243df9ea1d665d5eef78593c8d1031e4a3c61feb20267a974119a7f70d87d24/start

{
  "Detach": false,
  "Tty": false
}
```

Result:

```
锟絚bf83b97caceaeb98d449946cda46dba 3f5a14046fd530c8679dd7f67c15ec6570631d51 7995d69305583789568e85eeac0abf0c3c7166c4edb53afc5910e57ff0b37650 /sbin/apk 5830d01f7821b978df770b06db3790921 2a36b6f8f3992b112450e66ac128c2ea499a103e b4a2c06db38742e8c42c3c9838b285a7d8cdac6c091ff3df5ff9a15f1e41b9c7 /sbin/ldconfig 90292714bf3b5d86c997f10f64f92a50 f9ff078ddf9d9074b4dcee9965a230ee66fc9cb3 ab0f9ffe6fb1064ed2736c8191f841daaf54700f5e7b670e56fca7d7855dece8 /sbin/mkmntdirs
```

Comment: What exactly did you do to allow unencrypted access on port 2375?  That's potentially a major security issue – anyone who can reach that port can very easily root the entire system.  (Correspondingly consider using a Docker SDK instead of raw HTTP requests for this kind of task.)

Comment: The binary response data has a [framing protocol](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerAttach) so it starts with an 8-byte header identifying the stream and block length, but I'd be a little surprised to see it render as Chinese characters.  Do you have a hex dump of the first 16 bytes or so of the response?